# Issue with importing resources using Terraformer

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws, terraform-provider, terraform-state, terraform-import

I am trying to use Terraformer ( https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/terraformer ) to import some of our legacy into Terraform for ease of maintainability going forward. I keep running into a few issues though.

Current State - I am on Terraform version 1.1.7 with a remote backend configuration on S3. The desired end state is to use Terraformer to generate configurations for the legacy infrastructure, and include them as a separate module in the backend remote state.

Problem(s) -

1. Terraformer only seems to work with Terraform version 0.21.31, and the state files it generates also confides in this. I did some lookup and the standard suggestion here was to use https://github.com/tfutils/tfenv and have multiple Terraform versions. However it seems that TF 0.21.31 does not support provider plugin sources, which means I can't install the Hashicorp AWS provider plugin, without which, Terraformer can't work. So I am stuck in a deadlock here. Curious to know how others solved it?
2. Assuming I do somehow manage to solve the version issue, Terraformer seems to generate a local state file. Now, since my remote backend is on S3, how do I merge this local state file to the remote backend state file, so that Terraform realises that I am just planning to import some infra, and not re-create them?

Any help here would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Please let me know if we need some more additional info for a better prognosis!

Comment: Care to elaborate how providers cannot be used with 0.12.31?

Comment: It seems that 0.12.31 does not support source while listing providers. As a result, I am not able to install the Hashicorp AWS provider.

Please check the screenshot here - [link](https://imgur.com/a/1kwvveH).

Resulting .terraform folder after `terraform init` with TF 1.1.7 - [link](https://imgur.com/a/jMTIG3k).
Resulting .terraform folder after `terraform init` with TF 0.21.3 - [link](https://imgur.com/a/qvnDrCy).

Comment: If i try running Terraformer import using the latter, it fails with the following error - [link](https://imgur.com/a/CQQp6s5)

Comment: You just need a different type of provider declaration, that does not mean it cannot be used. There are also tools to help you upgrade step by step, from 0.12.x to 0.15.x which should help you with 1.x.x versions.